# Comparing two range of cells A and D and copy the duplicate data

Tags: excel, vba

If A & D match, paste A into G. Then add B & E and place the results in column H. Im having the problem to add value from B & E into H.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim RowNo As Long
    Dim LR As Long

    Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D100", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A100", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each d In rng1
    LR = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("F1:F" & LR).Formula = "=H1+C1"
        If Not d.Value = "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, d) > 0 Then
            RowNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(d, rng2)

            If d.Offset(, 1).Value = "" Then d.Offset(, 3).Resize(1).Value _
            = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & RowNo).Value

            If d.Offset(, 1).Value = "" Then d.Offset(, 4).Resize(1).Value _
            = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & RowNo).Value
        End If
    Next d
End Sub
```

Example cells:

```
A   1           X   22      A 45
B   2           C   33      C 36
C   3           A   44      F 105
D   4           Y   55      
E   5           J   66      
F   6           O   77      
G   7           T   88      
                F   99      
                W   11
```

Comment: What's the question/problem?

Comment: I sense a typo in this phrase `value from B and E will be paste in cell E`.  Did you mean `E` twice?

Comment: Your code compares A & D and copies to G just fine.  Please explain what you're having difficulty with explicitly.  And I don't understand your example.  What's the issue with B and E again?  Are you comparing them and then copying to E and overwriting it's value?  Is that the intent?

Comment: I can compare A & D and get the result A,C & F as shown. My problem is to add the value from B and E to H and get the value 45,36 and 105. There is something wrong with my code by the way im still a newbie to vba.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO).  Please update your question with these issues instead of putting them in the comments.  So you're trying to say with your code if `A` & `D` match, paste `A` into `G`.  Then add `B` & `E` and place the results in `H`?

Answer (score 0):

if the Problem is only to put the right numbers into H, use this code for that. Put it just be for "end Sub".
The code supposes you are never having more than 1000 rows filled in A and D, but you can change that.

```
Range("H1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUMIF(R1C1:R1000C1,RC[-1],R1C2:R1000C2)+SUMIF(R1C4:R1000C4,RC[-1],R1C5:R1000C5)"
Selection.Copy
Range("H2:H" & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(7))).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("H1:H" & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(7))).Select
'the following lines are only necessary if you don't want a formula in H.
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

hope that helps!
Max